# Create multiplatform installer in python

Tags: python

My project in python has many scripts in many files. General structure is 
:

```
Project/
|-- bin/
   |-- project
        |--calculations
           |--some scripts
        |--mainApp
           |--some scripts
        |--interpolations 
           |--some scripts
        |--more files
           |--other scripts     
|
|-- tests
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

I have many imports like this

```
import bin.project.mainApp.MainAppFrame
```

My setup.py file is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
name = 'Application to orifices',
version = '1.0',
author = "Michał Walkowiak",
author_email = "michal.walkowiak93@gmail.com",
description = "Application in python 3.4 with noSQL BerkleyDB",
packages = find_packages(),
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'PracaInzynierska = bin.project.mainApp.MainApp:__init__'
    ]
},
scripts = [
    'bin/project/mainApp/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/mainApp/MainApp.py',
    'bin/project/mainApp/MainAppFrame.py',

    'bin/project/informations/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/informations/DisplayInformations.py',
    'bin/project/informations/InformationsFrame.py',

    'bin/project/calculations/Calculate.py',
    'bin/project/calculations/UnitConversion.py',

    'bin/project/databaseHandler/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/databaseHandler/databaseHandler.py',

    'bin/project/databaseMonitoring/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/databaseMonitoring/DatabaseFrame.py',
    'bin/project/databaseMonitoring/DisplayDatabase.py',

    'bin/project/initializeGUI/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/initializeGUI/CalculationsFrame.py',
    'bin/project/initializeGUI/initGui.py',

    'bin/project/interpolation/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/interpolation/Interpolate.py',

    'bin/project/orificeMethods/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/orificeMethods/methodsToCountOrifice.py',

    'bin/project/steamMethods/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/steamMethods/methodToCountParamsSteam.py',

    'bin/project/waterMethods/__init__.py',
    'bin/project/waterMethods/methodsToCountParamsWater.py'
    ]

)
```

I use setup.py with

```
    python3 setup.py bdist --formats=gztar
```

It's generate dist folder with tar.gz file but when I unpack it every script is in /bin folder. When I try to run MainApp.py by

```
    python3 MainApp.py
```

I receive an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "MainApp.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bin.project.mainApp.MainAppFrame
    ImportError: No module named 'bin'
```

When I change

```
    import bin.project.mainApp.MainAppFrame
```

to

```
    import MainAppFrame
```

it works but it doesn't in Pycharm where localy there are paths to every file. 
Is there any option to generate istaller, which after unpack would have the same paths as the orginal project, or it always add all files to one folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I used, for a simple GUI (tkinter) program:

- Windows: copy the Python folder and create a portable version, then launch the program by creating a shortcut i.e. `python.exe ../foo/start.py`. Use Nullsoft Installer to create the installation file that will take care of the links, directories and uninstall steps on Windows systems.
- Linux: distribute the code, specify the dependencies, create a script that creates links for an executable. Of course, you can browse info on how to create your own package, i.e. for Debian.
- All other: similar as for Linux.

That's one of the beauties of Python.

Comment: Well, sorry but it is a bit too general for me. I work on linux and as you can see in question I already have tried to do something like you said and the problem is keeping paths to scripts after: 'python3 setup.py bdist --formats=gztar'.
P.S I used QtDesigner to build GUI if that matters